# IPTables - Simple Routing of all traffic

Tags: iptables

Ubuntu 14.04.2 VM, with IP of 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5.
I'm trying to route all traffic for 1.2.3.5 to another address of 1.2.3.189 (which is on another server, and can be reached by any machine on the network).
In the **/etc/sysctl.conf**: I enabled set the **net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1**

I've reset everything with this script
`echo "Stopping firewall and allowing everyone..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

I've then ran this as my script to handle the traffic
`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -d 1.2.3.5 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.189`

ufw is disabled, and I can't think of much else to do.
Ideally (and down the road) the traffic would be sent to a second NIC, connected to a different Network (10.0.0.189), but I figured lets start with the simplest first.

Comment: what "iptables -nvL" gives you ?

Comment: I performed the same procedure that you are using with the same ips, and everything was fine. How are you executing this test? "ping"? Can you check if this ip 1.2.3.189 are with firewall down?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that `1.2.3.5` and `1.2.3.189` are on same subnet, server `1.2.3.189` will try to reply with its own IP (layer 2).

you should also `SNAT` returning packets from `1.2.3.189` to `1.2.3.5` adding :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 1.2.3.189 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.5
```

Comment: Here is my **iptables -t nat -L**  

**Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)**
`DNAT       all  --  anywhere             1.2.3.5          to:1.2.3.189`  
  
_Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)_
_target     prot opt source               destination_
  
_Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)_ 
_target     prot opt source               destination_
  
**Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)**
`SNAT       all  --  1.2.3.189          anywhere             to:1.2.3.5`  
  
If I have the above rules enabled: ping and web requests to 1.2.3.5 fail.  However, ping and web requests to 1.2.3.189 always work.